# How to make a box just large enough for a certain element inside?

Tags: html, css

Consider a document like this:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>test</title></head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="..." alt="" style="clear:both" />
<p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</body></html>
```

The image (in my case it's actually an embedded SVG generated ad-hoc) has a size that is not known beforehand. How is it possible that the enclosing div has a width that is just large enough to hold the image (i.e. such that the paragraph below breaks at the same width as the image above)?

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920401/how-to-simulate-hfill-with-html-and-css/14921863#14921863). The code I am currently working on can be found [here](https://fuz.su/%7Efuz/yase/). The text above the board should have the same width as the board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished using `display:table` and a set minimal width. I used `width:1px` in the sample below, but any minimal width would work.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="..." alt="" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    width: 1px;
    display: table;
}
```

The result will look something like this:

[image]

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EzPpT/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use float to fit the container

```
<div style="float:left;background:yellow;">
    <img ...>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

or you can try (doesn't work with IE7... but you can probably fix it)

```
<div style="display:inline;display:inline-block;background:yellow;">
    <img ...>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

and newer mozilla and webkit browsers have

```
<div style="width:fit-content;margin:0 auto;background:yellow;">
   <img ...>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what will happen with your SVG, but in the `<svg>` declaration you can specify the actual render size of the vectors AFAIK

hoping to be helpful..

Comment: I actually set the width using a certain javascript later on. It would be nice if I had to change the width in only one place.